# Jasmine/karma test case are not running in an orderly manner using Angular5

Tags: unit-testing, angular5, karma-jasmine

When running the test case using jasmine/karma test cases. I am facing n issue which is before starting with the Login spec test case the other spec files are all called before completing the Login. It need to happen in an orderly manner which is like

1.Login
2.Dashboard
3.Order
  etc.

Is there a way to do this.

**login.spec.ts file**

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { RouterModule, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { LoginComponent } from './login.component';
import { DebugElement } from '@angular/core';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { BrowserModule, By } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { Ng2Bs3ModalModule } from 'ng2-bs3-modal/ng2-bs3-modal';
import { RouterTestingModule } from '@angular/router/testing';
import { APP_BASE_HREF } from '@angular/common';
import { LoginService } from './login.service';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from '../config/api.service';
import { ConfigService } from '../config/config.service';
import { Constants } from '../config/Constant';
import { SharedService } from '../shared/shared.service';
import { Http, BaseRequestOptions, ResponseOptions, Response, RequestMethod } from '@angular/http';
import { inject } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { MockBackend, MockConnection } from '@angular/http/testing';

describe('LoginComponent', () => {
  let comp: LoginComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<LoginComponent>;
  let de: DebugElement;
  let el: HTMLElement;
  let userNameEl: DebugElement;
  let passwordEl: DebugElement;
  let submitEl: DebugElement;
  let loginService: LoginService = null;
  let backend: MockBackend = null;

  TestBed.overrideComponent(LoginComponent, {
    set: {
      providers: [
        {
          provide: LoginService,
          useValue: loginService
        },
        {
          provide: Router,
          useClass: class { navigate = jasmine.createSpy('navigate'); }
        }
      ]
    }
  });


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    // loginService = loginService;
    // backend = mockBackend;
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        LoginComponent
      ],
      imports: [
        RouterModule.forRoot([{
          path: '',
          component: LoginComponent
        }]),
        BrowserModule,
        FormsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        Ng2Bs3ModalModule,
        RouterTestingModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [
        MockBackend,
        BaseRequestOptions,
        {
          provide: Http,
          useFactory: (backendInstance: MockBackend, defaultOptions: BaseRequestOptions) => {
            return new Http(backendInstance, defaultOptions);
          },
          deps: [MockBackend, BaseRequestOptions]
        },
        LoginService,
        ApiService,
        ConfigService,
        Constants,
        SharedService,
        { provide: APP_BASE_HREF, useValue: '/' }
      ]
    }).compileComponents().then(() => {
      fixture = TestBed.createComponent(LoginComponent);
      comp = fixture.componentInstance;
      de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('form'));
      el = de.nativeElement;
      userNameEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=InputEmail1]'));
      passwordEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('input[id=InputPassword1]'));
      submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.login-btn'));
    });
  }));

  beforeEach(inject([LoginService, MockBackend], (Service: LoginService, mockBackend: MockBackend) => {
    loginService = Service;
    backend = mockBackend;
  }));


  it('should create', () => {
    expect(comp).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('To check the initial value', () => {
    expect(comp.submitted).toBe(false);
    expect(comp.spinnerlogo).toBeFalsy();
    expect(comp.data).toEqual({});
  });

  it(`entering value in username and password input controls`, () => {
    userNameEl.nativeElement.value = 'admin';
    passwordEl.nativeElement.value = 'admin';
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('after entering value the button should enabled and click Action should happen', () => {
    expect(submitEl.nativeElement.disabled).toBeFalsy();
    const loginButtonSpy = spyOn(comp, 'onSubmit');
    submitEl.triggerEventHandler('click', null);
    expect(loginButtonSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  it('calling onSubmit method after clicked the login button', () => {
    comp.submitted = true;
    comp.spinnerlogo = true;
    comp.errorDiagnostic = null;
    comp.mailerrorDiagnostic = null;
    expect(comp.submitted).toBeTruthy();
    expect(comp.spinnerlogo).toBeTruthy();
    expect(comp.errorDiagnostic).toBeNull();
    expect(comp.mailerrorDiagnostic).toBeNull();
  });

  it('#login should call endpoint and return it\'s result', (done) => {
    backend.connections.subscribe((connection: MockConnection) => {
      const options = new ResponseOptions({
        body: JSON.stringify({ success: true })
      });
      connection.mockRespond(new Response(options));

      // Check the request method
      expect(connection.request.method).toEqual(RequestMethod.Post);
      // Check the url
      expect(connection.request.url).toEqual('/auth/login');
      // Check the body
      // expect(connection.request.text())
      expect(connection.request.text()).toEqual(JSON.stringify({ username: 'admin', password: 'admin' }));
      // Check the request headers
      expect(connection.request.headers.get('Content-Type')).toEqual('application/json');
    });

    loginService.login('admin', 'admin')
      .subscribe((response) => {
        console.log('response values are ---####------------ ', response);
        // Check the response
        expect(response.user.username).toEqual('admin');
        expect(response.user.password).toEqual('admin');
        // set value in sessionStorage
        sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(response));
        sessionStorage.setItem('token', JSON.stringify(response.token));
        sessionStorage.setItem('dismissOrders', 'false');

        done();
      },
        (error) => {
          expect(error).toThrowError();
        });
  });

});
```

the main problem is before executing the above file . The other spec file are executed

Thanks,
Kishan

Comment: Please post your code

Comment: I have posted the login component spec file. This login spec file should run and after that it should move to dashboard but before running the login the another component spec files are running.

Comment: Are you not mocking the login component in your other component spec files ? Your other spec files shouldn't need to do any login so you wouldn't have this problem of having to run things in a certain order (order shouldn't matter and you have no control over that anyway).

Comment: so basically you are saying if I need any login response for getting access token, I need to perform mocklogin in every spec file and set localstorage for it

Comment: Pretty much - you shouldn't be testing login in your other components. Presumably your other components have the loginservice injected as a constructor parameter so it can be mocked out.

Comment: Thank you @auburg